# Adaptive image adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

What is a cool CSS3 method to ensure an image will occupy window-height with `min-width:50%` and `max-width:100%;` depending on the size of the image?

So if the image is good quality and greater than the resolution of the screen/viewport, it will behave as a `background-size:cover;` and if not, it will occupy atleast 50% of the screen real estate.

Thanks.
*PS - If CSS3 can't do, JS method is cool but otherwise could be preferred as a fall-back*

```css
  html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  /*background: #fff;*/
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#layout {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

#cover {
 background:  #EFEFEF;
  flex: 0 0 30rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height:100%
}

.hold-img{width: inherit;height: inherit;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
<div id="cover">
      
      <div class="hold-img" style="background-image:url('http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/251ba9d4b7db2c58ef46af60de813ebe/f9xcnp12WNl7B64E5MPAkpznF7v.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;background-size:cover;"></div>
     
</div>

<!-- 
Big Image - http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/251ba9d4b7db2c58ef46af60de813ebe/f9xcnp12WNl7B64E5MPAkpznF7v.jpg

Half-image - http://wac.450f.edgecastcdn.net/80450F/comicsalliance.com/files/2014/03/SpaceJam02.jpg
-->
</div>
```

Comment: What are you classing as `good quality`?

Comment: That when filling the entire window, it wont appear pixelated.

Comment: Then you'll need to analyse the original size of the image, check how wide the viewport is, and then continuous update this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
.the_img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px; 
}
```

For max-width you will add the width of the image so it doesn't go beneath that.

http://jsfiddle.net/abb2sghh/